# Will it help in this problem to convert the string into a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question. I am not looking for the answer to this exercise, just a pointer. My question is: will this be easier to solve if the two-word string is converted to a List?

> ANIMAL CRACKERS: Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter
>
> animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama') --> True
>
> animal_crackers('Crazy Kangaroo') --> False

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please do not shout.

Comment: Yup, but to a list, having words as its elements (so split by either space, or no-word regex: ```[^\w+]```).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this problem it would help to use the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to split the string into a list of the two words.

Generally, the same data can be represented in different ways, and you want to use a representation which aligns with what you need to do with the data. Since this problem is about words, then "a list of words" aligns closer with what you need to do than "a string with two words" does.

Having a list of words allows you to write code that refers to "the first word" (i.e. `words[0]`) and "the second word" (i.e. `words[1]`). There is no comparably-simple way to refer to individual words in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I realised quite soon after i posted that the .split() function was what i needed to use. This was my solution.

```
def animal_crackers(string):
    twoWords = (string.split(' '))
    if twoWords[0][0].upper() == twoWords[1][0].upper():
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a split on the string input `myListOfTwoSriting = stringInput.split(" ")`, next split the 2 string link that : `firstletter = myListOfTwoSriting [0].split("")[0]` then `firstletterOfSeconde = myListOfTwoSriting [1].split("")[0]` for the seconde.
next:

1. `if firstletter == firstletterOfSeconde :
       return True
   else:
       return False`

Comment: You can also use `.lower()` of each firstletter variable for transforme 'P' to 'p'